# Make in memory copy of tensorflow 2 object detection model in python

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I trained a tensorflow 2 object detection model and load it like this in python:

```
detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load(model_dir)
```

Now I want to copy the `detect_fn` in memory.

With `tf.keras.models.clone_model(model)`
I got an exception: `Expected model argument to be a Model instance, got <tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x7fb23a2852e8>`

and with `copy.deepcopy(detect_fn)`
I got an exception: `can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`

I saved the model with the tensorflow script exporter_main_v2.py

My cloning code:

```
model_copy =  tf.keras.models.clone_model(model)
model_copy.build()
model_copy.set_weights(model.get_weights())
```

How can I clone/copy this model?

Regards
Oli

Comment: Why not use ```tf.keras.models.load_model``` to load the model ?

Comment: I tried this and the model loads and works. But cloning fails also with: `Expected model argument to be a Model instance, got , <tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x7f7195138e80>`

Comment: Correction: with `tf.keras.models.load_model` the loading ends up with an error: `packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py, line 114, in parse_saved_model
    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: saved_model.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
>>> model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/workdir/6/model/")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`